# Change URL in emailt gitlab-EE

Tags: gitlab

Has anyone ever installed gitlab EE, I'm having a case in my model, nginx acts as a proxy with the domain https://gitlab.abc.com which will point to the ip of the gitlab server: proxypass : http://ip.xxxx:80
and my gitlab, I configure external_url : http://ip.x.x.x.x
But the thing is, when the user sends a forgot password email, the email content with the link is in the form of ip, not the domain, so please tell me how to configure it so that the forgotten password email content is in the domain form. ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by uncommenting some lines in the gitlab.rb config

```
external_url 'https://domain'
nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['*', '[::1]']
nginx['listen_port'] = 8081
nginx['proxy_protocol'] = false
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location ^~ /foo-namespace/bar-project/raw/ {\n deny all;\n}\n"
nginx['real_ip_trusted_addresses'] = ['ip for server proxy]
```

at the proxy server i proxypass to gitlab's nginx address at port 8081